# Deleting a vector of pointers passed to a class

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have an abstract `module` class that specific modules derive from. At runtime, I parse a config file and determine the specific module type of each module within the config file:

```
std::vector<module*> modules;
module *temp;

//Let nm be the result of parsing as a std::string

if(nm == "type1")
{
    temp = new module_1(...);
}
else if(nm == "type2")
{
    temp = new module_2(...);
}
else if(nm == "type3")
{
    temp = new module_3(...);
}
else
{
    //Syntax error
    return -1;
}

modules.push_back(temp);
partition p;
p.modules = modules;
```

handing off the vector `modules` to a `partition` class:

```
class partition
{
    public:
    //Member functions

    private:
    //...Other variables
    std::vector<module*> modules;
};
```

What's the proper way to deallocate the memory for these module pointers once I'm done with them? I tried to delete them in the destructor for the `partition` class as follows, but wound up with a segmentation fault:

```
partition::~partition()
{
    for(unsigned i=0; i<modules.size(); i++)
    {
         delete modules[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you decide to use `std::vector<module*>` instead of `std::vector<module>` ?

Comment: @LihO I assume he is using virtual functions.

Comment: @Lalaland is correct. `module_1` derives from `module`, etc.

Comment: @Adam27X My immediate guess is that you are double deleting your modules. Use a private copy constructor to ban copies.

Comment: Can you post a simple example program that creates the seg fault?  The code sample look alright, so I think the issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: @Lalaland My immediate thought as well except that in that case, shouldn't he be getting a double free/heap corruption error?  At least in gcc those are different from a seg fault.

Comment: Have you looked at this using `gdb`? Where does it die?

Comment: If the vector held smart pointers, this would be trivial: `modules.clear();`. and I concur with Lalaland. Odds are your modules are being double-deleted, especially if the object holding the vector holding the pointers (i.e. `partition`) is ever copied.

Comment: Also, to answer the question: [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) would be a good way to verify that the modules are deleted once and only once.

Comment: @Lalaland concur. or `std::shared_ptr` if more than one holder of the module pointer is required, but the premise is certainly the same; pointers should not "own" resources unless they have brains (i.e. they're smart pointers).

Comment: `return -1;` is an issue, should return `NULL` instead. and partition should follow rule of three.

Comment: @RageD It dies when I try to call a member function of the `module` class after I pass the `partition` to a `package` class and then to a number of pthreads. I think the issue is that I don't perform a deep copy, as mentioned below by pmr.

Comment: @Adam27X how do you pass partition to package, by value or reference?

Comment: @billz I pass the partition to package by value and the package to each pthread by reference.

Comment: That's why you get double delete. pass package by value causes a copy... try to pass by reference. Also make it thread safe

Comment: @billz In the code above, should the `p.modules = modules` also be changed to pass `modules` by reference?

Comment: nope, that should pass by value. but how do you make sure each pointer in vector is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on how you want to handle ownership and if a partition is going to have value semantics. Think about what should happen if you copy a partition:

Is the copy of the partition going to share the modules with the original. Are changes in a module to be shared between the partitions?

If yes, you should use a `std::shared_ptr` for your partitions. All pain is gone.

If not, implement a copy-constructor and assignment operator for your partition that performs a deep-copy of the modules list. Implement a destructor that deletes each module in the list. This is safe, because each partition has its own module objects.

In general, I favor the second approach. If you don't want to implement the deep-copy, just make `partition` noncopyable or move-only and use `std::unique_ptr` to handle the deletion.

Comment: I do pass an instance of the `partition` class to another class `package`. An instance of the `package` class is then passed to some number of threads that work with the modules within. Each partition has its own set of modules, so the second approach seems relevant. Do I need a deep copy for the `package` class as well for this case?

Comment: @Adam27X Are the module objects thread-safe (i.e. more than a single thread can use the same module object)?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes. A given module itself is never accessed by more than one thread, but in the current state of my code, each thread does have access to all modules, even if it will only ever use its particular subset of them.

Comment: it will actually be easier if each thread has access to all modules in a partition, and only uses the ones it needs. how you setup that mutual exclusion is another task entirely. but the copy-nature of a partition (and thus the module table it is hoisting around) may well be better served by `shared_ptr` rather than `unique_ptr` (assuming I understand the problem correctly). Either way, pmr's answer (this one) is accurate.

Comment: @WhozCraig Much of it depends if you think about a `module` as a value or an object and how changes in one module should be propagated. In any case: One deep-copy in the hierarchy is enough.

Comment: @pmr I was able to get smart pointers for my `partition` class to work, thanks for your help. I'm still a bit confused though: Do I still need to manually delete all of the modules within each partition manually as I did in the code above?

Comment: @Adam27X No, that is what smart pointers are taking care of. You still have to make sure you don't have any cycles in your ownership graph (and break them with `weak_ptrS`), but I don't think this is the case given what you have described.